# Save only layer mask in Gimp

Tags: layer, mask, gimp

I've created a layer mask on an image in Gimp.

How can I just save just the layer map as a png?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using GIMP interactively, just have the layer mask selected as active drawable as you choose file save - select to save as .png or other file format of your choice (but .xcf).

If you are writing a plug-in using the procedure database, the gimp_file_save function takes a drawable as a parameter - this drawable should be your layer mask.

Comment: Please note that as of GIMP 2.8 this no longer works: the full image is always saved instead. There is an updated answer for newer GIMP versions  here:
http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/50896/gimp-export-layer-mask-as-png/50951#50951